# Create a Bundle Product via Magento API SOAP V2

Tags: api, soap, bundled-product, bundle, bundle-product

I'm using API SOAP V2 to create products in my store (1.8.1.0) from a custom ERP. Everything is going well when I try it with simple products. But now I need create a bundle product.

I'm doing it with catalogProductCreate method, like this:

```
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'bundle', '11', 'product_sku_b3', 
    array(
        'categories' => array(2),
        'websites' => array(1),
        'name' => 'Product ERP b3',
        'description' => 'Product description',
        'weight' => '1.0',
        'status' => '1',
        'visibility' => '4',
        'sky_type' => '1',//It is not necessary for a simple product
        'price' => '100',
        'tax_class_id' => 1,
        'stock_data ' => array(
            'qty' => '49',
            'is_in_stock' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

The problem: how to create bundle options and associate products to bundle options.
In the method docs there is nothing about bundle options: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html

The attribute sku_type (dynamic or fixed) does not work too.

Any Ideas?